# Label not available in Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBus.ServiceBusMessage

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus

I am migrating to Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus and have noticed that there is now no longer a property called Label

This is a huge problem as Label is used in our service bus rules to filter messages on a subscription.

What is the equivalant of setting message using the Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus and ServiceBusMessage

If I have to use Subject thats really bad because I would have to change every single rule in our service bus which is a total nightmare

Cheers

Paul

Comment: Your post is missing a question. For feedback, please refer to the GitHub repo of the relevant nuget package

Comment: I recall that `subject` property is there in its place. check it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.servicebusmessage.subject?view=azure-dotnet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is the equivalant of setting message using the Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus and ServiceBusMessage

That'd be the `Subject` property.

> If I have to use Subject thats really bad because I would have to change every single rule in our service bus which is a total nightmare

You don't need to change anything on the broker side. The SDK (`Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus`) is a client-side SDK. Subject will be converted to `Label` and you don't need to modify the existing subscriptions rules. See documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-filter-examples#filter-on-system-properties).